# Angular4 FormArray's removeAt function closes modal

Tags: angular

I have a problem with my angular4 application. There is a modal made with ng2-modal package. The modal contains a reactive form which consists of some FormGroups and FormArray. I can add and remove dynamically elemnts to/from this FormArray. Removing elemnts from this FormArray uses function removeAt and the problem is that when this function is used it closes  the modal. Does anybody know how to prevent this?

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, OnChanges, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'modal-component',
  template: require('./modal-component.html')
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('modal') modal;
  @Input() myObject;
  @Output() updateMyObjectEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({});
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    this.myObject = changes.myObject.currentValue;
    if (changes.myObject.currentValue != null) {

      this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(this.myObject.id, [Validators.required]),
        content: new FormControl(this.myObject.content, [Validators.required]),
        options: new FormArray(this.myObject.options ? this.prepareOptionFormGroups(this.myObject.options) : [])
      });
    }
  }

  prepareOptionFormGroups(options): [] {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      result.push(new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(options[i].id, [Validators.required]),
        value: new FormControl(options[i].value, [Validators.required])
      }));
    };
    return result;
  }


  addOption(): void {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['options'];
    control.push(this.initializeOption());
  }

  initializeOption(): any {
    return new FormGroup({
      value: new FormControl('Option', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  removeOption(index) {
    const control = this.myForm.controls['options'];
    control.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

Comment: please post your code ..

Comment: @vikk I just posted the code

Comment: Can you try passing in `$event` to your `removeOption` function and do `$event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some time of researching in the Internet I've decided to use `stopPropagation` function and it worked! My function after modification looks like this:

```
removeOption(index, event: Event) {
    const control = this.myForm.controls['options'];
    control.removeAt(index);
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

I would like to thanks everybody for trying to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.preventDefault();`.In your component code modify your code to

```
removeOption(index,event:Event) {

    const control = this.myForm.controls['options'];
    control.removeAt(index);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

  }
```

Let me know if it doesnt work

Comment: I've added this code to my view 
    button( type="button", (click)="removeOption(index, $event)" ) 
and the code You posted to modal-component, but it didn't help.

Comment: Nothing changed and there is no error in the console.  If any occurred in the console it would be much easier to find what causes this behaviour of the modal.